# Casting between EventArgs

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime

I'm having a hard time trying to access my original `FileActivatedEventArgs` when Navigating between pages in my Windows Runtime App.

When Navigating between pages, the EventArgs become `NavigationEventArgs` and whenever I try to cast it to `FileActivatedEventArgs` it throws an error.

I can't even cast it to `System.EventArgs` to do some inheritance from that point

Can anyone help me with this?

I call `Frame.Navigate(***,args)` to navigate between pages.

The page which makes the call:

```
protected void IsPurchased(FileActivatedEventArgs args)
{
    Frame.Navigate(typeof(Mypage),args)
}
```

The page which receives the call

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    StorageFile SF;
    SF = (FileActivatedEventArgs)e;
}
```

Comment: What is the (full) error? What is the (full) code throwing the error?

Comment: Error 5 Cannot convert type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs' to 'Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation.FileActivatedEventArgs'

Comment: Read the description of Navigate method http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms602269(v=vs.110).aspx and its arguments, then http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.navigationservice.navigated(v=vs.110).aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.navigationeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass a parameter to `Navigate`, this parameter is not passed directly to the `NavigatedTo` event; it's passed as a property of the `NavigationEventArgs`.

To retrieve it, you should do something like this:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    var fileActivatedArgs = (FileActivatedEventArgs)e.Parameter;
    var file = fileActivatedArgs.Files[0];
}
```